# Hibernate statistics analysis for statelessSession

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have activated Hibernate statistics and I'm running a stored procedure which is returning large number of records through a **StatelessSession** which is retrieved from sessionFactory. Later, the results will be written to a file using a **ScrollableResultset**.

Hibernate is configured to use connection pool and session context is thread.

This is my code:

```
StatelessSession session= sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("EXEC myStoredProcedure");
sessionFactory.getStatistics().logSummary();
```

Then the scrollable result set will be handed to a writter and eventually after all the records were written to a file it will be closed.

I ran this part of code few times as below:

**first time**

> Sessions opened: 11
>   Sessions closed: 10
>   Transactions: 6
>   Successful transactions: 6
>   Optimistic lock failures: 0
>   Flushes: 3
>   Connections obtained: 11
>   Statements prepared: 9
>   Statements closed: 0

**second time**

> Sessions opened: 17
>   Sessions closed: 16
>   Transactions: 12
>   Successful transactions: 12
>   Optimistic lock failures: 0
>   Flushes: 5
>   Connections obtained: 17
>   Statements prepared: 12
>   Statements closed: 0

**third time**

> Sessions opened: 20
>   Sessions closed: 19
>   Transactions: 15
>   Successful transactions: 15
>   Optimistic lock failures: 0
>   Flushes: 6
>   Connections obtained: 20
>   Statements prepared: 13
>   Statements closed: 0

**fourth time**

> Sessions opened: 23
>   Sessions closed: 22
>   Transactions: 18
>   Successful transactions: 18
>   Optimistic lock failures: 0
>   Flushes: 7
>   Connections obtained: 23
>   Statements prepared: 14
>   Statements closed: 0

After the second time as you can see the number of connections obtained were increasing by 3 each time.

My questions are: 
1) why the number is increasing  by 3 and not just one? 
2 ) why there is always one less Sessions closed? I mean we have (in case of third time) 20 opened and 19 closed.